# Removing rows with total number of ID occurred not equal to a specific number in Pandas Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have the following data frame in Pandas:

```
ID   rank   feature
1    1      3
1    2      6
1    3      8
1    4      6
2    1      2
2    2      9
3    1      0
3    2      3
3    3      1
4    1      3
4    2      9
4    3      0
4    4      5
4    5      1
5    1      2 
5    2      4
5    3      0
5    4      8
```

and I would like to delete all the rows such that the number in `ID` occurs in those rows is not equal to 4. For example, `ID` 1 occurs 4 times, `ID` 2 occurs 2 times, `ID` 3 occurs 3 times, `ID` 4 occurs 5 times and `ID` 5 occurs 4 times. So I would like to delete rows with `ID` = 2,3,4 and the output looks like:

```
ID   rank   feature
1    1      3
1    2      6
1    3      8
1    4      6
5    1      2 
5    2      4
5    3      0
5    4      8
```

Is there any computationally efficient way to do that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` to calculate the number of occurrences of each ID and then use simple filtering to get the result you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    "rank": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    "feature": [3, 6, 8, 6, 2, 9, 0, 3, 1, 3, 9, 0, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0, 8]
})

(
    df
    # count number of occurences and select only those rows whose ID is present 4 times
    .loc[lambda x: x.groupby("ID")["ID"].transform("count") == 4]
)
```

Which returns:

```
 ID  rank  feature
  1     1        3
  1     2        6
  1     3        8
  1     4        6
  5     1        2
  5     2        4
  5     3        0
  5     4        8
```